# A column is not able to be created in a MySQL DB?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to import a DB from remote host to my localhost through phpmyadmin so I am getting a strange problem that during importing a table I am not getting one field but when I checked the SQL file so it had that field mentioned in there to be created but oddly during importing or executing the SQL Queries manually the field is not created but when I tried that in another DB so worked perfectly now I am curious that what's the problem??

**Note :** And it's not just one field but instead it's a few fields one of them is the field namely as `coupon_banner_id`

Here is the SQL Query for Table as :

```
          -- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
          -- version 4.0.10.18
          -- https://www.phpmyadmin.net
          --
          -- Host: localhost
          -- Generation Time: Mar 26, 2017 at 09:22 AM
          -- Server version: 5.5.23-log
          -- PHP Version: 5.3.3

          SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
          SET time_zone = "+00:00";


          /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
          /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
          /*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
          /*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

          --
          -- Database: `drberg_com`
          --

          -- --------------------------------------------------------

          --
          -- Table structure for table `video`
          --

          CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `video` (
            `ID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            `coupon_banner_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
            `blog` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
            `catid` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
            `title` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
            `description` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
            `blogtopid` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
            `video` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
            `vlink` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
            `video_picture_alt` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
            `picture` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
            `apicture` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
            `usid` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
            `datein` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
            `koview` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
            `korating` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
            `kototrat` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
            `konota` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
            `kocomm` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
            `kofavorite` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
            `kofeatured` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
            `koorder` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '999',
            `commtime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
            `is_active` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
            PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
            KEY `coupon_banner_id` (`coupon_banner_id`)
          ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci CHECKSUM=1 DELAY_KEY_WRITE=1 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC AUTO_INCREMENT=1066 ;
```

Comment: Please list the MySQL version on which the issue occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `video` ..

Please check whether you already have an older 'video' table in that database. In such case the above query will not execute and the video table will retain the old schema which probably doesn't contain a few fields from the new schema.